# Why RecyclerView Adapter is a generic class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

> Class signature is RecyclerView.Adapter<"VH extends
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder">. VH type is
>   bounded by RecyclerView.ViewHolder.

As `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` is an abstract class, any instance of VH is inherited by `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

For example `onCreateViewHolder` method returns the generic VH type object, which is inherited from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` in any case. So why don't just make `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` as a return type (instead of VH generic type) and make all this stuff without generic style?

Comment: Design pattern view holder: [Hold View Objects in a View Holder](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling#ViewHolder)

Comment: and this [link](https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-viewholder-pattern-example/)

Comment: I understand View Holder pattern. I don't understand why google designed RecyclerView.Adapter as generic class.

Comment: see `onBindViewHolder` method for example, it passes your custom `ViewHolder` as a parameter and you dont have to use any casts - the same applies to many other `Adapter`s methods

Comment: In any case my custom ViewHolder is derived by RecyclerVIew.ViewHolder. So if it would be RecyclerVIew.ViewHolder instad of VH(generic) as a pass parameter in this methods it would't be any cast issues. If i get it right, there is no troubles send derived class instance instad of base.

Comment: Now the user would have to cast the holder manually even if you had only 1 viewholder subtype in your adapter

Comment: You can pass RecyclerView.ViewHolder if you want but you have to do the typecast when you want to use your custom holder.
Also, this is helpful when you need to use multiple ViewHolder for a single adapter.

Comment: Now i see. It is needed when overriding onBindViewHolder, when calling custom ViewHolder methods. You helped me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Because you want your subclass of `RecyclerView.Adapter` to deal only with a particular `ViewHolder` type.

This is why the class signature allows you to specify a `VH` type. So that the class will be modeled after your needs; the methods `onBindViewHolder`, `onCreateViewHolder` will be adapted to deal only with your preferred `ViewHolder` sub-type.

Without generics, (the methods mentioned above would have `ViewHolder` rather than the generic `VH` type), you could return `SubViewHolder1` from `onCreateViewHolder` and try to cast the first parameter of `onBindViewHolder` to `SubViewHolder2` (and you would get a `ClassCastException`). Not that you would do it, but the code is allowing you do it. So why not set some constraints that would ease your life?

By taking advantage of the generic type, you are saying:

> This is my `Adapter` for a `RecyclerView`. This `Adapter` deals with only this `ViewHolder` sub-class. Nothing else.